# MySQL UPDATE query with nested SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've been doing some research and I've found that it's not quite possible to deliberately nest a `SELECT` query withing an `UPDATE` statement. I've seen there are some possible workarounds, involving creating a temporary virtual copy of the table, because apparently you can't update and select from the same table at the same time.

I have not been able to get any of the examples to work, so I'm back to square one. Below you will see the visual representation of what I'd like if it were simple.

The nested `SELECT` query will return 4 or 5 ids, and i'd like to update a column to `0` for each of those rows. I hope what I want to do makes sense.

Thanks for all your help and insight in advance.

```
UPDATE
    `my_table`
SET
    `my_column_1` = 0
WHERE 
    `id`
IN  (
    SELECT
        `id`
    FROM
        `my_table`
    WHERE
        `my_column_2` = 35
    AND
        `my_column_3` = 3
    AND
        `id` != 136
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you not just use `WHERE` like this:

```
UPDATE
    `my_table`
SET
    `my_column_1` = 0
WHERE 
    `my_column_2` = 35
    AND `my_column_3` = 3
    AND `id` != 136
```

This will just update the required rows without selecting them first.